# jQuery Setting an option on a select box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't seem to get this to work...

```
<select id="selectBox">
<option value="A">Number 0</option>
<option value="B">Number 1</option>
<option value="C">Number 2</option>
<option value="D">Number 3</option>
<option value="E">Number 4</option>
<option value="F">Number 5</option>
<option value="G">Number 6</option>
<option value="H">Number 7</option>
</select>

$('#selectBox option[value=C]').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Comment: you need to make at least one item selected in your select box for this to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you are trying to do a multi-select list box, why not:

```
$('#selectBox').val('C');
```